# **UPDATED** Python Programming based on user-defined methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Can someone help me with the correct code I should use please? I still haven't figured it out.

---

I've posted the code below and the error outcome I'm receiving below. Some ages are being reported incorrectly. Can someone help me with the correct code please? Thank you for your time and any assistance provided.

Someone below helped me figure out their birthdates.

(Sarah = 2000/08/01, Eric = 2009/08/02, Carter = 2009/07/28, Georgia = 2005/09/01)

---

This is the code:

```
from datetime import date

class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, birthdate):
    self.name = name
    self.birthdate = birthdate
  


def get_age(self):
    birthdate = self.birthdate
    today = date.today()
    if today.month >= birthdate.month and today.day >= birthdate.day:
        self.age = (today.year - birthdate.year)
    else:
        self.age = (today.year - birthdate.year) - 1
    return self.age
```

---

This is the outcome (some of the age tests are failing):

```
#TEST 1#
sara.get_name() returned Sara
inputs:

outputs:
----------
#TEST 2#
sara.get_height() returned 160
inputs:

outputs:
----------
#TEST 3#
sara.get_age() returned 20
inputs:

outputs:
----------
#TEST 4#
sara.get_description() returned Sara is 160 cm high and is 20 years old.
inputs:

outputs:
----------
#TEST 5#
eric.get_age() returned 10
inputs:

outputs:
----------
#TEST 6#
** ERROR **carter.get_age() returned 10
* EXPECTED * 11
inputs:

outputs:
----------
#TEST 7#
georgia.get_age() returned 14
inputs:

outputs:
```

Comment: It's a good idea to try and trim your code down to specifically the part that's causing an issue, to make your question more focused. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @CrazyChucky okay no problem. I didn't know but thanks for informing me

Comment: I updated my post to only have the code and error

Comment: `today.month >= birthdate.month or today.day > birthdate.day` is likely not what you want. It would evaluate to `True` when comparing today July 31 to birthdate August 15. I would calculate and compare Julian days or seconds since the Unix epoch, but it really depends on what your teacher expects. If you can put the complete text of your assignment into your question, that will help.

Comment: I submitted a further edit which cuts it down to just the parts involved. Note that, in future, for a question like this, it's good to show the input that generates the output. That is, we know that Carter's age was reported correctly and Georgia's wasn't, but what are their birthdates and what is today's date?

Comment: @CrazyChucky I'm just curious but isn't the other parts of the code relevant for anyone to understand it better?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I updated the code to just a "if" statement but now I'm not getting the outcomes. I'm getting an error stating `RuntimeErrorElement(RuntimeError,Error on line 22:
    return self.age
AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute 'age'`

Comment: A single `if` that creates and sets `self.age` if True but does not create `self.age` at all if False isn't what you want either.

Comment: @Mark If other parts of your code work fine and aren't involved in the error, it's usually best to leave them out. Including `get_name()`, for instance, just means people have more to read through to get to the part you're actually asking about. Ideally you want to include enough to fully describe the issue, and nothing more. This helps others answer, because you're doing the work of tracking down and isolating where the problem is.

Comment: Can anyone assist me please? It's my last question and I just need to get the correct outcomes

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a logic error in `get_age()`:

```
  def get_age(self):
    birthdate = self.birthdate
    today = date.today()
    if today.month >= birthdate.month and today.day >= birthdate.day:
      self.age = today.year - birthdate.year
    else:
      # haven't reached birthday yet
      self.age = (today.year - birthdate.year) - 1
    return self.age
```

Comment: I do want to believe it's `get_age(self)`, I'm just unsure where to change. I tried it with both as ">=" with "and", it didn't work. I'm getting the same outcome

Comment: In your else condition, I think you mean to have `subyear = 1` and `birthdate.year + subyear` -- sorry, I must have misread that before. Edit: I updated my comment

Comment: I updated the code to just "if". I would get a error stating  `RuntimeErrorElement(RuntimeError,Error on line 22:
    return self.age
AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute 'age'`

Comment: Yes, that is because you do not always set self.age. Have you tried using the code in my current comment?

Comment: I just checked and tried it out. It's close...now I'm getting one error remaining `#TEST 6#
** ERROR **carter.get_age() returned 10
* EXPECTED * 11
inputs:

outputs:`

Comment: What is `carter.birthdate`?

Comment: I'm unsure. It only says expected = 11 and "carter.get_age()" returned 10. It can either be by the year or by the month

Comment: Try testing your code with your own inputs, then, and see what the results are. That will help you troubleshoot it, or at least know what to ask about.

Comment: I can't. It inputs it's own "person" named 'eric, sarah, micharl, carter, georgia"

Comment: I'm found something but I'm unsure it can be helpful. I was reading something about the question saying `Try the test case where the person's birthday is March 29, 2000 and today's date is January 29, 2019. This person is 18 years old. What age does your code calculate? What about if the birthday is March 31, 2000?`

Comment: You can. Try out your code in your own script, or in the interactive Python interpreter. Create one or more `Person` objects with various `birthdate` attributes and then call their `get_age()` methods.

Comment: @Mark Ah, this is why I don't like assignments where they just invoke your code from a grading program. Change your get_age code to just `return self.birthdate`, which will be wrong but it will show you the data you're getting.

Comment: I know. I'm starting to hate it also but it's my last one so I'm hoping to just get it over with. What am I changing exactly?

Comment: I'm wondering if it should be an "if, elif, else" statement. Suggestions?

Comment: @Mark `def get_age(self): return self.birthdate.year*10000+self.birthdate.month*100+self.birthdate.day`. The output from that will be analogous to what the grading program is feeding you. Like `20000329`. You can then revert get_age back to your own code and test it yourself in an interactive Python session.

Comment: `** ERROR **carter.get_age() returned 20090728
* EXPECTED * 11
inputs:

outputs:`

Comment: Now I understand what you made me do. You made me figure out the birthdate. That's really impressive/smart

Comment: @rachelnwalker I got the birthdate for carter

Comment: `#TEST 5#
** ERROR **eric.get_age() returned 20090802
* EXPECTED * 10
inputs:

outputs:`

Comment: `#TEST 7#
** ERROR **georgia.get_age() returned 20050901
* EXPECTED * 14
inputs:

outputs:`